# How can I achieve RLS in Power BI report with data from analysis service using "Connect live" method? Manage Roles option getting greyed out

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

Manage Roles option under Modeling menu in power bi desktop getting greyed out when we use "Connect live" method to get data from analysis service for the report.

It is available when we use "Import" method to get the data.

We have a Power BI report which uses live connection to get data from azure analysis service. One requirement we have is to restrict the users to their relevant data alone. For example, a team lead should see the data of his/her team members alone. We tried Row Level Security (RLS) in Power BI to do this by creating roles and setting filter on required column and it works fine when we use the import data option from azure analysis service. But when we try to do the same using "Connect live" method, the "Manage Roles" option under Modeling ribbon gets greyed out in power bi desktop. I can't create roles and so no filtering.

Please help me on this. Also point me in the right direction if I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#considerations-and-limitations), "For Analysis Services or Azure Analysis Services lives connections, you configure Row-level security in the model, not in Power BI Desktop. The security option will not show up for live connection datasets."

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. Now I have created roles and added users to it in azure analysis services. But when I connect the AAS as a datasource for my power bi report, the rls is not working as expected i.e., user can view all the data instead of theirs alone. The solutions that I'm getting is to use the "effective username" (SSAS). In order to do so we need gateway connection. But with AAS I don't have any gateway connection. How can I pass the logged in username to the AAS model?